# How can I pass an angular request throught a spring filter before a validation?

Tags: angularjs, spring, servlet-filters

I have a XSS Filter in a back app (an app with JAVA, Spring...) and I need to check from a front app (Angularjs) if the input values are ok according to the filter before validate the rest of the content.

So far I have achieved that:

Form (AngularJS) -> Validations (AngularJS) -> Filter (Back, Spring) -> Store

I need:

Form (AngularJS) -> Filter (Back, Spring) -> Validations (AngularJS) -> Store

```
I have this filter in the back application.

<!--XSS filter-->
<filter>
    <display-name>XSSFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>XSSFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.filter.XSSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>XSSFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


And I need to clean the XSS info


    $scope.save = function ($event) {

    -> Here I need to clean the XSS info

    //Validate
    if (!$scope.validate()) {
        manageValidationErrors();
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should validate two times (anyway). Once on the frontend for simple problems (missing @ in email adress) and again on the backend (again missing @ but maybe also checks for reference tables, etc) before you write into your store. This would also solve your Problem, since you can validate on the server after XSS filter.

The problem with your suggested approach would be to send the data unvalidated to the server, apply XSS filter, send back to client to validate again and then send back to server, which would just loop forever.